# Why does `term-emulate-terminal` get executed every time `read-from-minibuffer` gets executed?

Tags: ivy, term, counsel

Why does `term-emulate-terminal` get executed every time I execute `counsel-switch-buffer` if and only if the `*terminal*` buffer is open in a window. If the `*terminal*` buffer is not in a window `term-emulate-terminal` does not get called.

I can't seem to pinpoint why `ivy`/`counsel` is causing this behavior, as it is screwing up my buffer workflow. Is it because of `ivy-read`?

---

This is the update I get from `debug-on-entry` for `term-emulate-terminal`. And I'm not quite sure how to decipher all of this since I usually use `edebug` for my debugging:

```lisp
Debugger entered--entering a function:
  (if (or inhibit-debug-on-entry debugger-jumping-flag) nil (let ((inhibit-debug-on-entry t)) (funcall debugger (quote debug))))
  debug--implement-debug-on-entry(#<process terminal> "\015\033[K\033[01;32mi@debord\033[00m:\033[01;34m~\033[00m$ ")
  apply(debug--implement-debug-on-entry (#<process terminal> "\015\033[K\033[01;32mi@debord\033[00m:\033[01;34m~\033[00m$ "))
  term-emulate-terminal(#<process terminal> "\015\033[K\033[01;32mi@debord\033[00m:\033[01;34m~\033[00m$ ")
  read-from-minibuffer("Switch to buffer: " nil (keymap (keymap (11 . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)) keymap (up . ivy-previous-line) (down . ivy-next-line) (jd:M-ret . jd:preview-function) (jd:M-bks . ivy-switch-buffer-kill) (jd:C-bks . jd:delete-word-backward) (jd:tab . ivy-partial) (jd:ret . ivy-alt-done) (C-M-k . ivy-next-history-element) (C-M-i . ivy-previous-history-element) (M-u . beginning-of-line) (M-o . end-of-line) (M-l . ivy-alt-done) (M-k . ivy-next-line) (M-j . counsel-up-directory) (M-i . ivy-previous-line) (M-\; . swiper-recenter-top-bottom) (C-u . ivy-beginning-of-buffer) (C-o . ivy-end-of-buffer) (C-k . jd:ivy-scroll-up-command) (C-i . jd:ivy-scroll-down-command) (C-g . minibuffer-keyboard-quit) (36 . ivy-magic-read-file-env) (3 keymap (19 . ivy-rotate-sort) (1 . ivy-toggle-ignore) (15 . ivy-occur)) (33554464 . ivy-restrict-to-matches) (15 . hydra-ivy/body) (22 . ivy-scroll-up-command) (prior . ivy-scroll-down-command) (next . ivy-scroll-up-command) (7 . minibuffer-keyboard-quit) (right . ivy-forward-char) (32 . self-insert-command) (18 . ivy-reverse-i-search) (remap keymap (describe-mode . ivy-help) (kill-ring-save . ivy-kill-ring-save) (kill-whole-line . ivy-kill-whole-line) (kill-line . ivy-kill-line) (scroll-down-command . ivy-scroll-down-command) (scroll-up-command . ivy-scroll-up-command) (end-of-buffer . ivy-end-of-buffer) (beginning-of-buffer . ivy-beginning-of-buffer) (kill-word . ivy-kill-word) (forward-char . ivy-forward-char) (delete-char . ivy-delete-char) (backward-kill-word . ivy-backward-kill-word) (backward-delete-char-untabify . ivy-backward-delete-char) (delete-backward-char . ivy-backward-delete-char) (previous-line . ivy-previous-line) (next-line . ivy-next-line)) (9 . ivy-partial-or-done) (10 . ivy-alt-done) (nil keymap (1 . ivy-read-action) (15 . ivy-dispatching-call) (111 . ivy-dispatching-done) (25 . ivy-insert-current-full) (105 . ivy-insert-current) (106 . ivy-yank-word) (114 . ivy-toggle-regexp-quote) (97 . ivy-toggle-marks) (16 . ivy-previous-line-and-call) (14 . ivy-next-line-and-call) (118 . ivy-scroll-down-command) (112 . ivy-previous-history-element) (110 . ivy-next-history-element) (10 . ivy-immediate-done) (13 . ivy-call)) (mouse-3 . ivy-mouse-dispatching-done) (mouse-1 . ivy-mouse-done) (down-mouse-1 . ignore) (13 . ivy-done)) nil ivy-history)
  (condition-case err (read-from-minibuffer prompt (progn (or (and (memq (type-of ivy-last) cl-struct-ivy-state-tags) t) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote ivy-state) ivy-last))) (aref ivy-last 5)) (make-composed-keymap keymap ivy-minibuffer-map) nil hist) (error (if (equal err (quote (error "Selecting deleted buffer"))) nil (signal (car err) (cdr err)))))
  (if (and ivy-auto-select-single-candidate ivy--all-candidates (null (cdr ivy--all-candidates))) (progn (progn (or (and (memq (type-of ivy-last) cl-struct-ivy-state-tags) t) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote ivy-state) ivy-last))) (let* ((v ivy-last)) (aset v 23 (car ivy--all-candidates)))) (setq ivy-exit (quote done))) (condition-case err (read-from-minibuffer prompt (progn (or (and (memq (type-of ivy-last) cl-struct-ivy-state-tags) t) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote ivy-state) ivy-last))) (aref ivy-last 5)) (make-composed-keymap keymap ivy-minibuffer-map) nil hist) (error (if (equal err (quote (error "Selecting deleted buffer"))) nil (signal (car err) (cdr err))))))
  (let* ((hist (or history (quote ivy-history))) (minibuffer-completion-table collection) (minibuffer-completion-predicate predicate) (ivy-height (ivy--height caller)) (resize-mini-windows (if (display-graphic-p) nil (quote grow-only)))) (if (and ivy-auto-select-single-candidate ivy--all-candidates (null (cdr ivy--all-candidates))) (progn (progn (or (and (memq (type-of ivy-last) cl-struct-ivy-state-tags) t) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote ivy-state) ivy-last))) (let* ((v ivy-last)) (aset v 23 (car ivy--all-candidates)))) (setq ivy-exit (quote done))) (condition-case err (read-from-minibuffer prompt (progn (or (and (memq ... cl-struct-ivy-state-tags) t) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... ivy-last))) (aref ivy-last 5)) (make-composed-keymap keymap ivy-minibuffer-map) nil hist) (error (if (equal err (quote (error "Selecting deleted buffer"))) nil (signal (car err) (cdr err)))))) (if (eq ivy-exit (quote done)) (progn (ivy--update-history hist))))
  (progn (add-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (let* ((hist (or history (quote ivy-history))) (minibuffer-completion-table collection) (minibuffer-completion-predicate predicate) (ivy-height (ivy--height caller)) (resize-mini-windows (if (display-graphic-p) nil (quote grow-only)))) (if (and ivy-auto-select-single-candidate ivy--all-candidates (null (cdr ivy--all-candidates))) (progn (progn (or (and (memq ... cl-struct-ivy-state-tags) t) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... ivy-last))) (let* ((v ivy-last)) (aset v 23 (car ivy--all-candidates)))) (setq ivy-exit (quote done))) (condition-case err (read-from-minibuffer prompt (progn (or (and ... t) (signal ... ...)) (aref ivy-last 5)) (make-composed-keymap keymap ivy-minibuffer-map) nil hist) (error (if (equal err (quote ...)) nil (signal (car err) (cdr err)))))) (if (eq ivy-exit (quote done)) (progn (ivy--update-history hist)))))
  (unwind-protect (progn (add-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (let* ((hist (or history (quote ivy-history))) (minibuffer-completion-table collection) (minibuffer-completion-predicate predicate) (ivy-height (ivy--height caller)) (resize-mini-windows (if (display-graphic-p) nil (quote grow-only)))) (if (and ivy-auto-select-single-candidate ivy--all-candidates (null (cdr ivy--all-candidates))) (progn (progn (or (and ... t) (signal ... ...)) (let* (...) (aset v 23 ...))) (setq ivy-exit (quote done))) (condition-case err (read-from-minibuffer prompt (progn (or ... ...) (aref ivy-last 5)) (make-composed-keymap keymap ivy-minibuffer-map) nil hist) (error (if (equal err ...) nil (signal ... ...))))) (if (eq ivy-exit (quote done)) (progn (ivy--update-history hist))))) (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook))
  (let ((fun (function ivy--minibuffer-setup)) setup-hook) (setq setup-hook (function (lambda nil (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (funcall fun)))) (unwind-protect (progn (add-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (let* ((hist (or history (quote ivy-history))) (minibuffer-completion-table collection) (minibuffer-completion-predicate predicate) (ivy-height (ivy--height caller)) (resize-mini-windows (if (display-graphic-p) nil (quote grow-only)))) (if (and ivy-auto-select-single-candidate ivy--all-candidates (null (cdr ivy--all-candidates))) (progn (progn (or ... ...) (let* ... ...)) (setq ivy-exit (quote done))) (condition-case err (read-from-minibuffer prompt (progn ... ...) (make-composed-keymap keymap ivy-minibuffer-map) nil hist) (error (if ... nil ...)))) (if (eq ivy-exit (quote done)) (progn (ivy--update-history hist))))) (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook)))
  (unwind-protect (let ((fun (function ivy--minibuffer-setup)) setup-hook) (setq setup-hook (function (lambda nil (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (funcall fun)))) (unwind-protect (progn (add-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (let* ((hist (or history ...)) (minibuffer-completion-table collection) (minibuffer-completion-predicate predicate) (ivy-height (ivy--height caller)) (resize-mini-windows (if ... nil ...))) (if (and ivy-auto-select-single-candidate ivy--all-candidates (null ...)) (progn (progn ... ...) (setq ivy-exit ...)) (condition-case err (read-from-minibuffer prompt ... ... nil hist) (error ...))) (if (eq ivy-exit (quote done)) (progn (ivy--update-history hist))))) (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook))) (let ((session (or (plist-get extra-props :session) (if (or (minibufferp) (null ...) (eq ... ...)) nil caller)))) (if session (progn (progn (or (and (memq ... cl-struct-ivy-state-tags) t) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... ivy-last))) (let* ((v ivy-last)) (aset v 27 (plist-put extra-props :ivy-data ...)))) (ivy--alist-set (quote ivy--sessions) session ivy-last)))) (ivy--cleanup))
  (let* ((ivy-recursive-last (and (active-minibuffer-window) ivy-last)) (ivy--display-function (if (or ivy-recursive-last (not (window-minibuffer-p))) (progn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-display-functions-alist caller))))) (setq update-fn (or update-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-update-fns-alist caller))) (setq unwind (or unwind (ivy-alist-setting ivy-unwind-fns-alist caller))) (setq ivy-last (make-ivy-state :prompt (ivy--update-prompt prompt) :collection collection :predicate predicate :require-match require-match :initial-input initial-input :history history :preselect preselect :keymap keymap :update-fn (if (eq update-fn (quote auto)) (function (lambda nil (let (...) (save-current-buffer ...)))) update-fn) :sort sort :action (ivy--compute-extra-actions action caller) :multi-action multi-action :frame (selected-frame) :window (selected-window) :buffer (current-buffer) :unwind unwind :re-builder re-builder :matcher matcher :dynamic-collection dynamic-collection :display-transformer-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy--display-transformers-alist caller) :directory default-directory :extra-props extra-props :caller caller :def def)) (ivy--reset-state ivy-last) (unwind-protect (let ((fun (function ivy--minibuffer-setup)) setup-hook) (setq setup-hook (function (lambda nil (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (funcall fun)))) (unwind-protect (progn (add-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (let* ((hist ...) (minibuffer-completion-table collection) (minibuffer-completion-predicate predicate) (ivy-height ...) (resize-mini-windows ...)) (if (and ivy-auto-select-single-candidate ivy--all-candidates ...) (progn ... ...) (condition-case err ... ...)) (if (eq ivy-exit ...) (progn ...)))) (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook))) (let ((session (or (plist-get extra-props :session) (if (or ... ... ...) nil caller)))) (if session (progn (progn (or (and ... t) (signal ... ...)) (let* (...) (aset v 27 ...))) (ivy--alist-set (quote ivy--sessions) session ivy-last)))) (ivy--cleanup)) (ivy-call))
  (progn (let ((init-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-init-fns-alist caller))) (if init-fn (progn (funcall init-fn)))) (if (equal overriding-local-map (quote (keymap))) (progn (keyboard-quit))) (setq caller (or caller this-command)) (let* ((ivy-recursive-last (and (active-minibuffer-window) ivy-last)) (ivy--display-function (if (or ivy-recursive-last (not (window-minibuffer-p))) (progn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-display-functions-alist caller))))) (setq update-fn (or update-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-update-fns-alist caller))) (setq unwind (or unwind (ivy-alist-setting ivy-unwind-fns-alist caller))) (setq ivy-last (make-ivy-state :prompt (ivy--update-prompt prompt) :collection collection :predicate predicate :require-match require-match :initial-input initial-input :history history :preselect preselect :keymap keymap :update-fn (if (eq update-fn (quote auto)) (function (lambda nil (let ... ...))) update-fn) :sort sort :action (ivy--compute-extra-actions action caller) :multi-action multi-action :frame (selected-frame) :window (selected-window) :buffer (current-buffer) :unwind unwind :re-builder re-builder :matcher matcher :dynamic-collection dynamic-collection :display-transformer-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy--display-transformers-alist caller) :directory default-directory :extra-props extra-props :caller caller :def def)) (ivy--reset-state ivy-last) (unwind-protect (let ((fun (function ivy--minibuffer-setup)) setup-hook) (setq setup-hook (function (lambda nil (remove-hook ... setup-hook) (funcall fun)))) (unwind-protect (progn (add-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook) (let* (... ... ... ... ...) (if ... ... ...) (if ... ...))) (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook))) (let ((session (or (plist-get extra-props :session) (if ... nil caller)))) (if session (progn (progn (or ... ...) (let* ... ...)) (ivy--alist-set (quote ivy--sessions) session ivy-last)))) (ivy--cleanup)) (ivy-call)))
  (progn (let ((--cl-keys-- --cl-rest--)) (while --cl-keys-- (cond ((memq (car --cl-keys--) (quote (:predicate :require-match :initial-input :history :preselect :def :keymap :update-fn :sort :action :multi-action :unwind :re-builder :matcher :dynamic-collection :extra-props :caller :allow-other-keys))) (setq --cl-keys-- (cdr (cdr --cl-keys--)))) ((car (cdr (memq ... --cl-rest--))) (setq --cl-keys-- nil)) (t (error "Keyword argument %s not one of (:predicate :require-match :initial-input :history :preselect :def :keymap :update-fn :sort :action :multi-action :unwind :re-builder :matcher :dynamic-collection :extra-props :caller)" (car --cl-keys--)))))) (progn (let ((init-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-init-fns-alist caller))) (if init-fn (progn (funcall init-fn)))) (if (equal overriding-local-map (quote (keymap))) (progn (keyboard-quit))) (setq caller (or caller this-command)) (let* ((ivy-recursive-last (and (active-minibuffer-window) ivy-last)) (ivy--display-function (if (or ivy-recursive-last (not ...)) (progn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-display-functions-alist caller))))) (setq update-fn (or update-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-update-fns-alist caller))) (setq unwind (or unwind (ivy-alist-setting ivy-unwind-fns-alist caller))) (setq ivy-last (make-ivy-state :prompt (ivy--update-prompt prompt) :collection collection :predicate predicate :require-match require-match :initial-input initial-input :history history :preselect preselect :keymap keymap :update-fn (if (eq update-fn (quote auto)) (function (lambda nil ...)) update-fn) :sort sort :action (ivy--compute-extra-actions action caller) :multi-action multi-action :frame (selected-frame) :window (selected-window) :buffer (current-buffer) :unwind unwind :re-builder re-builder :matcher matcher :dynamic-collection dynamic-collection :display-transformer-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy--display-transformers-alist caller) :directory default-directory :extra-props extra-props :caller caller :def def)) (ivy--reset-state ivy-last) (unwind-protect (let ((fun (function ivy--minibuffer-setup)) setup-hook) (setq setup-hook (function (lambda nil ... ...))) (unwind-protect (progn (add-hook ... setup-hook) (let* ... ... ...)) (remove-hook (quote minibuffer-setup-hook) setup-hook))) (let ((session (or ... ...))) (if session (progn (progn ... ...) (ivy--alist-set ... session ivy-last)))) (ivy--cleanup)) (ivy-call))))
  (let* ((predicate (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :predicate))))) (require-match (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :require-match))))) (initial-input (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :initial-input))))) (history (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :history))))) (preselect (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :preselect))))) (def (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :def))))) (keymap (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :keymap))))) (update-fn (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :update-fn))))) (sort (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :sort))))) (action (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :action))))) (multi-action (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :multi-action))))) (unwind (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :unwind))))) (re-builder (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :re-builder))))) (matcher (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :matcher))))) (dynamic-collection (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :dynamic-collection))))) (extra-props (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :extra-props))))) (caller (car (cdr (plist-member --cl-rest-- (quote :caller)))))) (progn (let ((--cl-keys-- --cl-rest--)) (while --cl-keys-- (cond ((memq (car --cl-keys--) (quote ...)) (setq --cl-keys-- (cdr ...))) ((car (cdr ...)) (setq --cl-keys-- nil)) (t (error "Keyword argument %s not one of (:predicate :require-match :initial-input :history :preselect :def :keymap :update-fn :sort :action :multi-action :unwind :re-builder :matcher :dynamic-collection :extra-props :caller)" (car --cl-keys--)))))) (progn (let ((init-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-init-fns-alist caller))) (if init-fn (progn (funcall init-fn)))) (if (equal overriding-local-map (quote (keymap))) (progn (keyboard-quit))) (setq caller (or caller this-command)) (let* ((ivy-recursive-last (and (active-minibuffer-window) ivy-last)) (ivy--display-function (if (or ivy-recursive-last ...) (progn ...)))) (setq update-fn (or update-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy-update-fns-alist caller))) (setq unwind (or unwind (ivy-alist-setting ivy-unwind-fns-alist caller))) (setq ivy-last (make-ivy-state :prompt (ivy--update-prompt prompt) :collection collection :predicate predicate :require-match require-match :initial-input initial-input :history history :preselect preselect :keymap keymap :update-fn (if (eq update-fn ...) (function ...) update-fn) :sort sort :action (ivy--compute-extra-actions action caller) :multi-action multi-action :frame (selected-frame) :window (selected-window) :buffer (current-buffer) :unwind unwind :re-builder re-builder :matcher matcher :dynamic-collection dynamic-collection :display-transformer-fn (ivy-alist-setting ivy--display-transformers-alist caller) :directory default-directory :extra-props extra-props :caller caller :def def)) (ivy--reset-state ivy-last) (unwind-protect (let ((fun ...) setup-hook) (setq setup-hook (function ...)) (unwind-protect (progn ... ...) (remove-hook ... setup-hook))) (let ((session ...)) (if session (progn ... ...))) (ivy--cleanup)) (ivy-call)))))
  ivy-read("Switch to buffer: " internal-complete-buffer :keymap (keymap (11 . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)) :preselect "ivy.el" :action ivy--switch-buffer-action :matcher ivy--switch-buffer-matcher :caller ivy-switch-buffer)
  ivy-switch-buffer()
  (let ((ivy-update-fns-alist (quote ((ivy-switch-buffer . counsel--switch-buffer-update-fn)))) (ivy-unwind-fns-alist (quote ((ivy-switch-buffer . counsel--switch-buffer-unwind))))) (ivy-switch-buffer))
  counsel-switch-buffer()
  funcall-interactively(counsel-switch-buffer)
  call-interactively(counsel-switch-buffer nil nil)
  (prog1 (call-interactively cmd record-flag keys) (if (and (symbolp cmd) (get cmd (quote byte-obsolete-info)) (not (get cmd (quote command-execute-obsolete-warned)))) (progn (put cmd (quote command-execute-obsolete-warned) t) (message "%s" (macroexp--obsolete-warning cmd (get cmd (quote byte-obsolete-info)) "command")))))
  (cond ((arrayp final) (if record-flag (progn (setq command-history (cons (list (quote execute-kbd-macro) final prefixarg) command-history)) (if (and (numberp history-length) (> history-length 0)) (progn (let (...) (if ... ...)))))) (execute-kbd-macro final prefixarg)) (t (prog1 (call-interactively cmd record-flag keys) (if (and (symbolp cmd) (get cmd (quote byte-obsolete-info)) (not (get cmd (quote command-execute-obsolete-warned)))) (progn (put cmd (quote command-execute-obsolete-warned) t) (message "%s" (macroexp--obsolete-warning cmd (get cmd ...) "command")))))))
  (let ((final cmd)) (while (progn (setq final (indirect-function final)) (if (autoloadp final) (setq final (autoload-do-load final cmd))))) (cond ((arrayp final) (if record-flag (progn (setq command-history (cons (list ... final prefixarg) command-history)) (if (and (numberp history-length) (> history-length 0)) (progn (let ... ...))))) (execute-kbd-macro final prefixarg)) (t (prog1 (call-interactively cmd record-flag keys) (if (and (symbolp cmd) (get cmd (quote byte-obsolete-info)) (not (get cmd ...))) (progn (put cmd (quote command-execute-obsolete-warned) t) (message "%s" (macroexp--obsolete-warning cmd ... "command"))))))))
  (if (and (symbolp cmd) (get cmd (quote disabled)) disabled-command-function) (run-hooks (quote disabled-command-function)) (let ((final cmd)) (while (progn (setq final (indirect-function final)) (if (autoloadp final) (setq final (autoload-do-load final cmd))))) (cond ((arrayp final) (if record-flag (progn (setq command-history (cons ... command-history)) (if (and ... ...) (progn ...)))) (execute-kbd-macro final prefixarg)) (t (prog1 (call-interactively cmd record-flag keys) (if (and (symbolp cmd) (get cmd ...) (not ...)) (progn (put cmd ... t) (message "%s" ...))))))))
  (let ((prefixarg (if special nil (prog1 prefix-arg (setq current-prefix-arg prefix-arg) (setq prefix-arg nil) (if current-prefix-arg (progn (prefix-command-update))))))) (if (and (symbolp cmd) (get cmd (quote disabled)) disabled-command-function) (run-hooks (quote disabled-command-function)) (let ((final cmd)) (while (progn (setq final (indirect-function final)) (if (autoloadp final) (setq final (autoload-do-load final cmd))))) (cond ((arrayp final) (if record-flag (progn (setq command-history ...) (if ... ...))) (execute-kbd-macro final prefixarg)) (t (prog1 (call-interactively cmd record-flag keys) (if (and ... ... ...) (progn ... ...))))))))
  command-execute(counsel-switch-buffer)
```

---

Even eliminating the extra arguments passed to `read-from-minibuffer` doesn't prevent `read-from-minibuffer` to somehow trigger `term-emulate-terminal`.

```lisp
...
term-emulate-terminal(#<process terminal> "\015\033[K\033[01;32mi@debord\033[00m:\033[01;34m~\033[00m$ ")
read-from-minibuffer("Switch to buffer: ")
...
```

Comment: `M-x debug-on-entry RET term-emulate-terminal RET`

Comment: Updated my question with what I get returned to me by using `M-x debug-on-entry RET term-emulate-terminal RET `.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, I'm seeing that `read-from-minibuffer` may be responsible for the undesired behavior I'm experiencing. But I don't know how in the world why.

Comment: Updated my question once again, eliminating the extraneous arguments passed to `read-from-minibuffer`; still exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: But if I manually invoke `read-from-minibuffer` via `eval-expression`, `term-emulate-terminal` doesn't get called.

Comment: It *might* not be directly connected -- perhaps Emacs is simply taking the opportunity to accept process output while waiting for you to do something in the minibuffer?  With `read-from-minibuffer` being C code, I'm unsure how that situation would present itself in the debugger.  However if you are *consistently* seeing the terminal buffer's process filter (which is what `term-emulate-terminal` is) being triggered only by this sequence of events, then it would seem to be connected somehow.

Comment: Does resizing the terminal window have the same effect?  Perhaps the inferior process is being told that's happening, and it is responding.

Comment: I suspect that's it.  I can see that `window-configuration-change-hook` calls `window--adjust-process-windows` to "Update process window sizes to match the current window configuration", which calls `set-process-window-size` for each process in each affected window.  That talks to the process, the process talks back, and so the process filter runs.

Comment: In principle, nothing about that should be "screwing up [your] buffer workflow".  What is the actual problem?

Comment: That has to be it. What is happening is that the `*terminal*` buffer window is somehow being selected during that whole process, so that it always stays as one of the top buffers in the buffers list, thus never actually moving down the list of buffers; something that I rely on heavily when switching buffers back and forth.

Comment: I don't know what the best approach to solving this would be, though.

Comment: I don't use ivy/counsel to switch buffers, so I don't know offhand how it's generating the sequence, but hopefully someone else can assist further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the *reason* for this is:

- Calling `counsel-switch-buffer` is triggering a window configuration change.
- `window-configuration-change-hook` contains `window--adjust-process-windows` to "Update process window sizes to match the current window configuration", which calls `set-process-window-size` for each process in each affected window, which talks to the process in question.
- If the process talks back, that's going to invoke the process filter (which is what `term-emulate-terminal` is, for `term` buffers).
- Per `(elisp)Accepting Output`, output from processes is normally handled "only while Emacs is waiting for some sort of external event, such as elapsed time or terminal input".  In the scenario in question, the first such opportunity is when `read-from-minibuffer` is called and awaiting user input.